# Recovering previous NBA headshot photos

Tags: nba, media

I'm looking to get NBA headshot photos from a few years ago, but it appears that NBA.com only keeps about the past 3 years. For example, there is [James Harden's 2017 photo](https://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/headshots/nba/1610612745/2017/260x190/201935.png), [James Harden's 2016 photo](https://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/headshots/nba/1610612745/2016/260x190/201935.png), and [James Harden's 2015 photo](https://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/headshots/nba/1610612745/2015/260x190/201935.png). However, what I would expect to be [James Harden's 2014 photo](https://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/headshots/nba/1610612745/2014/260x190/201935.png) does not exist. I'm wondering if previous years are stored using a different URL format, or where else previous photos might exist.